# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : unable to create new native Thread - Kill unused threads - JVM

Tags: java, linux, spring, multithreading, jvm

I am working on a project that is developed on spring mvc and is using wildfly as webserver.

I came across the exception of `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : unable to create new native Thread` and after some research I came to know that somehow the web app requests for more threads that it should request (probably thread pool is not utilized properly)..

I want to know is there anyway by which I can **kill n-used threads of JVM**** safely? one option is to go through the whole and check perform an analysis on where the actual leak is.

Another one could be to kill the unused threads safely so that resource could be made available to JVM when a new thread is requested.

I did run `ps huH p <PID_OF_U_PROCESS> | wc -l` and came to know that wildfly process is using 1022 threads. While the `max user process limit` is 1024

Comment: I really hate this particular error. A couple of questions. First, are you certain it is more threads than it "should" request? We've had this issue on both a server (where > 1024 was not wrong; had to change the process limit) and on a thick client. Second, how would you identify an "unused thread"? Third, do you mean "kill" in the Linux sense (e.g., kill at the bash prompt), or using Java to request a thread termination?

Comment: @KevinO ofcoruse using java request will be more feasible. The application is idle but the threads are still in use... 

If it can be done via some commands of JVM or shell, I will make a .sh and will execute it periodically ..

How do we update the process limit, I can try that as well..

Comment: In essence, get the list of all the threads, walk them, and then request each one to shut down. You can use the ThreadMXBean, recursively find the root ThreadGroup, or get all the stack traces. Based upon some determination that the thread should be shutdown, either use the specific method, or Thread.interrupt(). I am assuming, of course, that these are threads created by the application and not the wildfly server itself. If the latter, it is likely a correctable configuration issue. Definitely find who is creating these threads, and consider adding logic to the thread to autto shutdown.